# Update multiple rows in pandas based on a criteria to update one row with common value,

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
A.    B.        C.     
1    create.  Active
1    create.  Active
1.   create   Active
2.   create   Active
2.   create.  Active
2.   create   Active
```

If one of the values in b gets changed to "deploy"
then I want see that there is a deploy in column B.
I want to change C to running for that row and any
other row that has the same value in A.  In other
words, if any value in column B gets set to deploy,
I want to change C to running for all the rows
that.

So, if one of the Creates with 1 in A gets updated to
deploy, then I want the table to look like this:

'''`

```
A     B       C
1   create  Running
1   create  Running
1   deploy  Running
2   create  Active
2   create  Active
2   create  Active
```

`
'''

It seems like it should be able to be done,
But I just can't figure it out.

I could change C to Running in the same row as deploy,
but not the other two rows with a one in A.

Comment: The formatting of your expected output needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

```
   A       B       C
0  1  create  Active
1  1  create  Active
2  1  deploy  Active
3  2  create  Active
4  2  create  Active
5  2  create  Active
```

You can find all the `A` values that have a `deploy` and use `.isin()` to find the corresponding rows:

```
deployed = df.loc[ df['B'] == 'deploy', 'A' ]
df.loc[ df['A'].isin(deployed), 'C' ] = 'Running'
```

```
   A       B        C
0  1  create  Running
1  1  create  Running
2  1  deploy  Running
3  2  create   Active
4  2  create   Active
5  2  create   Active
```